# Compilation error with plsql procedure

Tags: plsql, ora-06550

Below is a plsql procedure which was written by someone else and I have asked to fix its compilation errors and run it right.

```
 PROCEDURE DropMyTable IS
  x                number;  
  TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
 --type NAME_TBL is table of VARCHAR2(30);
 --tab_Table                 NAME_TBL;
 tab_Table                VARCHAR2S(30);
 stmt                     VARCHAR2(4096);
  stmt2                    VARCHAR2(4096);
    outerCur                 cur_typ;
      rows                     NATURAL := 1000;
    TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST     EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, -942);
  BEGIN
 stmt2 := 'select distinct G_Tab  from G_SERVE  where G_TYPE=''CAP'''; 
  --Begin
   OPEN outerCur FOR stmt2;
   LOOP
    FETCH outerCur BULK COLLECT INTO
      tab_Table LIMIT rows;
   EXIT WHEN tab_Table.COUNT = 0;

   FOR i IN 1..tab_Table.COUNT LOOP
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Drop the  tables in G_SERVE.G_TAB
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*** Drop  table: ' || tab_Table(i) || ' ***');
      -- BEGIN
      --First drop the optable      
      stmt := 'DROP TABLE ' || tab_Table(i) || '_OPTAB CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;  
      --drop the base table
      stmt := 'DROP TABLE ' || tab_Table(i) || ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
      --drop the Package
      stmt := 'DROP PACKAGE  ' || tab_Table(i) || '_PKG';
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;     
    EXCEPTION
  -- When the table, optab and package  doesn't exist,
  -- ignore error "ORA-00942: table, optab or package does not exist".
   WHEN TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('table, optab or package does not exist');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(9));
   --Re-raises any other errors.
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error!');
    RAISE;
     END;
  END LOOP;
 END LOOP;
 --END;
 END DropMyTable;
```

First up I have commented out 4th and 5th line of code from begging and changed it to what it looks like now ( 6th line from the top).

Other thing I have commented out 2 BEGIN keywords first commented out "BEGIN" can be seen after

```
  stmt2 := 'select distinct gao_table  from GAO_SERVICESIFACE  where GAO_TYPE=''CAPABILITY''';
```

and the second "BEGIN" keyword has been commented out  after the following line of code.

```
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*** Drop  table: ' || tab_Table(i) || ' ***');
```

Since I suspect that whoever has written this code put unnecessary "BEGIN" keyword (i apologize if I'm wrong as I'm  not a plsql expert. But doing all the commenting out thing i got rid of so many errors).

But when I compile the above code I still get following 2 errors.

1)

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 27, column 7:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:
>  ;
>  ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
>  pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier>
>  <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
>  continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>  savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
> ```

2)

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 38, column 9:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:
>    ;
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You have commented out the BEGIN inside the inner loop but not its associated EXCEPTION and END.  You need that begin.  Also you cannot change an array to a scalar variable while the code still expects an array (references to `tab_Table(i)` etc.)

Decent indentation of code always makes it easier to follow:

```
PROCEDURE DropMyTable IS
  x                number;  
  TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
  type NAME_TBL is table of VARCHAR2(30);
  tab_Table                 NAME_TBL;
  --tab_Table                VARCHAR2S(30);
  stmt                     VARCHAR2(4096);
  stmt2                    VARCHAR2(4096);
  outerCur                 cur_typ;
  rows                     NATURAL := 1000;
  TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST     EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, -942);
BEGIN
  stmt2 := 'select distinct G_Tab  from G_SERVE  where G_TYPE=''CAP'''; 
  --Begin
  OPEN outerCur FOR stmt2;
  LOOP
    FETCH outerCur BULK COLLECT INTO
      tab_Table LIMIT rows;
    EXIT WHEN tab_Table.COUNT = 0;

    FOR i IN 1..tab_Table.COUNT LOOP
      --------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Drop the  tables in G_SERVE.G_TAB
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*** Drop  table: ' || tab_Table(i) || ' ***');
      BEGIN
        --First drop the optable      
        stmt := 'DROP TABLE ' || tab_Table(i) || '_OPTAB CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;  
        --drop the base table
        stmt := 'DROP TABLE ' || tab_Table(i) || ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
        --drop the Package
        stmt := 'DROP PACKAGE  ' || tab_Table(i) || '_PKG';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;     
      EXCEPTION
        -- When the table, optab and package  doesn't exist,
        -- ignore error "ORA-00942: table, optab or package does not exist".
        WHEN TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('table, optab or package does not exist');
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(9));
        --Re-raises any other errors.
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error!');
          RAISE;
      END;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
--END;
END DropMyTable;
```

I have reinstated that BEGIN and restored the array.  I don't know if there is anything else wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but now when I compile the code you modified I get following errors. Error report:
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'STMT2' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 8:
PLS-00201: identifier 'OUTERCUR' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 11:
PLS-00201: identifier 'OUTERCUR' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 8, column 15:
PLS-00201: identifier 'TAB_TABLE.COUNT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 10, column 17:
PLS-00201: identifier 'TAB_TABLE.COUNT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 10, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:                                                                                   I made 2 comments in order to show you all the errors I get because of limited words in this space.

Comment: And the other thing I thought that even if we decalre a variable of type  VARCHAR2S it also behaves like an array.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but you seem to be losing everything before the first BEGIN somehow.  I just compiled this procedure on my database with no errors.

Comment: I just pasted the successful creation into my answer.

Comment: Thanks buddy appreciate your help.